# How to use polymorphism with the Unity editor

Tags: c#, unity

For example:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class A
{
    [SerializeField]
    public int x;
}
public class TestA : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public A a = new A();
}

[System.Serializable]
public class B : A
{
    [SerializeField]
    public int y;
}
public class TestB : TestA
{
    // Not legal, I know. Considering Unity forbids the use of constructors in 
    // monobehaviour classes, I have no idea how I'd do this.
    a = new B();
}
```

Given that this MonoBehaviour class "TestA" exposes an "A" object, I'd like to override this default value so that when a MonoBehaviour of type "TestB" is attach to a game object in the editor, an object of type "B" is exposed.

Perhaps I'm better off looking into creating custom property drawers, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this with the default editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with your approach.

**Unity doesn't support serialization of polymorphic custom classes** not derived from ScriptableObject or MonoBehaviour.

In other words, it doesn't matter where and how you initialized `a` field, if `B` if an instance of `A` it will be sliced of (or won't be serialized at all I don't remember exactly I need to check).

Similar to this [answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/98994/unity-inspector-not-showing-serialized-variables-of-child/99000#99000).

A clarification:

```
a = new B();
```

This is legal. You don't instantiate certain classes using constructors (such as `MonoBehaviours`) becasue those are resources allocated in the **unmanaged C++** side of the engine. `MonoBehaviour` are just `C# wrappers` for the relative components.
For everything whose lifetime and ownership is just managed by `mono runtime`, than you can use constructors.

Comment: So, basically it has to be a MonoBehaviour component, and attached manually in the editor?

Comment: A MonoBehaviour or ScriptableObject. Not necessary attached by hand. You can use CreateInstance and do it by code.